# How to get Multiple Inputs

Tags: yii

I was thinking of implementing picture uploading to my web application.

Now there are few Uncertainties.It would be great if some one makes them clear.

How do you allow user to upload multiple data for

**Example**. I have a model for `car` and I want user to add *as many pictures with comments*. Usually on websites there is button that says "Add another picture". If user clicks that button or link a text field and a Browse button appears and user can add as many pictures as he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through this wiki - 
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/176/uploading-multiple-images-with-cmultifileupload/